# use oracle to import data from Json file to smart contract

Tags: json, oracle, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I want to import data from a dataset on a JSON file to my smart contract in Remix. it is an academic project and I am not experienced in solidity. the dataset contains sports results and users place bets on matches in the project. smart contract gets results from the dataset through Oracle. the dataset is in a json file. Please give me some advice on this.

I think I need a Chainlink node and an external adapter, but I don't know how to find a proper one. I'm good at working with Python so if there is a way to get help from Python,  I welcome it.

Comment: Although I am not sure why you want to upload dataset to blockchain, for the existing massive data, it is not recommended to save them on chain. Storage and computing on blockchain are expensive. If you need to do it, you can create an API service and allow this api could be called by oracle, then you can leverage on the oracle service to get the data. Please refer to the [introduction](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions).

Comment: You can use chainlink Any API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink community node operator here.

There are many ways to accomplish this, but the easiest method would be to make your JSON available on the internet via a public URL (ie, upload it to Amazon S3 and make the bucket public), and ask an existing node operator (Chainlink oracle) to download / parse it / serve it on-chain for you. We host requests like this for many clients.

To find a Chainlink oracle, you can post your requirement in the Chainlink Official Discord server (**#operator-requests** channel), or you can use a known oracle's website (we at LinkWell Nodes have existing oracles / job ids posted within our documentation that will serve any internet-based data for you).

There are other options available to you as well, such as Chainlink Functions (for a self-service, decentralized approach, but you'll have to code up your request in JS), and hosting your own Chainlink node (feasible on any almost any machine with a Unix OS for a small-scale project, but requires a good deal of technical know-how to implement at any sort of scale).

Best of luck, and I hope that helps to answer your question!